# Move png's to appropriate folder in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv with two columns **Directory** and **Filename**. Each row in the csv shows what directory each file belongs like so

`Directory, File Name`

`DIR18, IMG_42.png`

`DIR12, IMG_16.png`

`DIR4, IMG_65.png`

So far I have written code that grabs each directory and filename from the csv and then all files at their destination like so:

movePng.py

```
import shutil
import os
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('/User/Results.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader: 
        for (k,v) in row.items(): 
            columns[k].append(v) 

source = '/User/PNGItems'

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    pngName = f[:-4]
    for filename in columns['File Name']:
        fileName = filename[:-4]
        if pngName == fileName
            # GET THIS POSITION IN columns['File Name'] for columns['Directory']
            shutil.move(f, source + '/' + DIRECTORY)
```

> How do I get the index of the columns['File Name'] and grab the corresponding directory out of columns['Directory'] ?

Comment: You can use `zip`, e.g.: `for filename, directory in zip(columns['File Name'], columns['Directory']):`

Comment: For getting the index of the columns['File Name'] you can use it:
`for i, filename in enumerate(columns['File Name']):`

Comment: Can i use that index to access the columns['Directory']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I used @Peter Wood suggestion and it worked beautifully. Also I had to modify shutil.

Here is the code below

```
for f in files:
    pngName = f[:-4]
    for filename, directory in zip(columns['File Name'], columns['Directory']):
        fileName = filename[:-4]
        if pngName == fileName:
            directoryName = directory[1:]
            shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), source + '/' + directoryName)
```

Comment: Yes, if you have folder mappings for exactly the files that are actually there this is more efficient than first reading the mapping into a dict.

Comment: Regarding your solution: you actually created an unnecessary O(n²) complexity algorithm that will get very slow for large files since you are looping over the whole mapping for each file. You are also doing the zipping  every time (though I think that's relatively cheap in modern versions of Python). If you go this way it would be better to just loop over the entries of the entries of the CSV file once and to handle missing files if necessary. The outer loop just makes the whole process unnecessarily slow.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the assignments into a dictionary and then query that:

```
folder_assignment_file = "folders.csv"

file_folder = dict()
with open(folder_assignment_file, "r") as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    for folder, filename in reader:
        file_folder[filename] = folder
```

And then get the target folder like so: `DIRECTORY = file_folder[fileName]`.

Some other hints:

- `filename`, `fileName` are not good variable names, this will only lead to hard to find bugs because Python is case sensitive
- use `os.path.splitext` to split the extension off the filename
- if not all your files are in one folder the `glob` module and `os.walk` might come in handy

**Edit:**

Creating the dict can be made even nicer like so:

```
with open(folder_assignment_file, "r") as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    file_folders = {filename: folder for folder, filename in reader}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test this out